# Text in two columns is not the same level (IEEE journal)

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column, multicol, ieeetran

I am a double-column journal using latex. The problem is that I want to remove this problem:

[image]

I mean I want both columns to end on the same level like this:

[image]

Please tell me what I should to do ? This is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEoj}


% Change all s 


%% New packages
\let\labelindent\relax
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{\smash{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{multirow,enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\AtBeginDocument{\definecolor{ojcolor}{cmyk}{0.93,0.59,0.15,0.02}}
\def\OJlogo{\vspace{-5pt}\includegraphics[height=20pt]{ojcoms.png}}
\begin{document}
\receiveddate{XX Month, XXXX}
\reviseddate{XX Month, XXXX}
\accepteddate{XX Month, XXXX}
\publisheddate{XX Month, XXXX}
\currentdate{XX Month, XXXX}
\doiinfo{OJCOMS.2022.1234567}

\title{TITLE}

\affil{AAAAA}

\affil{VVVV}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx,  xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx xxxxxxx.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\maketitle
\section{INTRODUCTION} 

\IEEEPARstart{A}BC \lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1] 
\section{aa}\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Not familiar with IEEEoj and my web search was not helpful..  Using IEEEtran showed no problem, other than undefined commands and needing to put `abstract` after `\maketitle`.

Comment: This may not solve the problem, but you may avoid others by trimming your preamble to avoid loading unnecessary packages.

Comment: This also happens in my case. It occurs when one column has content with a different style, such as an abstract, subtitle, figure, etc. I think this is common and not a problem.